# How to replace all occurrence of a symbol with awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

From the cmd (awk 'some expression') I got a result in the format

```
Key:(white_space)Value
Key:(white_space)Value
...
```

How to manipulate the result to be in the format:

```
Key=Value
```

I need this because I want to put the information into .properties file format which is key=value

In other words I need to replace `:` with `=` and remove the whitespace.

Is there a command in awk that can achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask for `awk`, while `sed` provides just as easy a solution. However, `awk` makes it trivial with `sub` as well:

```
awk '{ sub(/:[ \t]*/,"=") }1'
```

**Example**

```
$ echo "Key:       Value" | awk '{ sub(/:[ \t]*/,"=") }1'
Key=Value
```

Comment: Yes it is working It has removed the whitespaces too. You are right the question was about awk so it will be more precise from SO perspective to accept your answer. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach.

```sh
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $1 "=" $NF}' file.txt
```

Comment: That would fail if `Value` contained any colons or white space, e.g. `Name: Joe Shmo` or `Ratio: 5:1`.